Does SpaceX Starship have significant methane emissions?
SpaceX Starship apparently uses liquid methane and liquid oxygen as its fuel. Liquid methane is not ideal for its environmental problems (burning it creates CO2 which can't be captured from a rocket, and we don't have a cost-effective way of sequestering the emitted carbon dioxide from the atmosphere to create new methane via Sabatier reaction).
However, the ratio of oxygen to methane is according to Wikipedia only 3.6 : 1 and not the stoichiometric ratio of 4 : 1:

Raptor operates with an oxygen-to-methane mixture ratio of about 3.6:1, lower than the stoichiometric mixture ratio of 4:1 necessary for complete combustion, since operating a higher temperatures would melt the engine

Does this mean that a significant amount of the methane is left unburned? Methane is a very potent greenhouse gas, far more than carbon dioxide.
Or is the methane in the exhaust so hot that it would combine with atmospheric oxygen anyway, not leaving any unburned methane to the atmosphere?

My guess is that the amount of methane lost to the atmosphere during production/extraction of the methane used to fill the Startships is probably bigger than the amount of unburnt methane gas...

Because the Raptor engine is full flow staged combustion, I think that means it runs on a stoichiometric ratio and not fuel-rich like, I think, every other rocket engine used in flight.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor   IMHO this is an excellent question, and I wish someone had an actual solid answer.

Yes, the combustion is imperfect.  This is always done with big rockets because very hot oxygen is a very powerful oxidizer.  The standard saying is that if your engine runs oxygen rich it will soon run engine rich.  (Although there comes a point where you have so much oxygen that it doesn't get hot enough to eat the engine.  You would never actually run an engine that way but it is sometimes done with the oxygen turbopump since the exhaust can be directed into the main engine and use up the oxygen.)
However, look at the energy levels.  If you do not have complete oxidation the oxygen lowest energy state is when it burns to H2O and CO, rather than leaving some CH4 unburned.

The last sentence, though it sounds reasonable, could use some support - how can one "look at the energy levels"? In the particular case of rocket combustion and exhaust, how do we know most CH4 make it to at least CO? Is there any data to support that?

the necessary assumptions here are that in a rocket engine, you have good mixing and tons of excess energy, at which point the question just becomes what the lowest entropy combinations of products is.

@OscarSmith Exactly.  I was just looking at the bond energy.  There are 6 bonds (two of which are double bonds) in the fully reacted product, the lowest energy bond of those 6 is the one between CO and the second O.
